# ORA-06550 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:* & = - + ; < / >

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

What am I missing here?  It's tagging line 5 column 19....that semi-colon has to stay.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Patient_Audit_Trigger
  BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON Patient
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
       Operation VARCHAR(6);
BEGIN

    IF DELETING THEN 
      Operation := 'D';
    END IF;

    IF UPDATING THEN 
      Operation := 'U';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO Patient_Audit (patNo, patName, patAddr, patDOB, changeTime, changeBy, ActionType)
    VALUES (:old.patNo, :old.patName, :old.patAddr, :old.patDOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, USER, Operation);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to compile your trigger ( first of all I created Patient and Patient_Audit tables) and the only reason why it was unable to compile is that there is

```
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
```

which should be

```
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

CURRENT_TIME stamp has already time zone , unlike LOCALTIMESTAMP

This compiles

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Patient_Audit_Trigger
BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON Patient
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   Operation VARCHAR(6);
BEGIN

IF DELETING THEN 
  Operation := 'D';
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
  Operation := 'U';
END IF;

INSERT INTO Patient_Audit (patNo, patName, patAddr, patDOB, changeTime, changeBy, ActionType)
 VALUES (:old.patNo, :old.patName, :old.patAddr, :old.patDOB,    current_timestamp, USER, Operation);
END;
/
```

(Off topic: Note that use of VARCHAR is not encouraged, you should use VARCHAR2)